# How to get OpenCover to look at local bin\Debug folder for PDBs not GAC

Tags: c#, gac, opencover

I am using OpenCover 4.7.922 with nUnit console runner 3.10.0.

I have a `myproj.tests` project which tests `myproj`.

After building, `myproj.tests\bin\debug` contains `myproj.tests.dll`, `myproj.tests.pdb`, `myproj.dll`, `myproj.pdb`.

`myproj` is registered in the GAC.

I am calling OpenCover like so:

```
OpenCover.Console.exe -output:opencover.xml -register:user -target:"nunit3-console.exe" -targetargs:"myproj.tests\bin\debug\myproj.tests.dll --result=NUnitResults.xml"
```

`opencover.xml` contains

```
<Module skippedDueTo="MissingPdb" hash="DD-83-09-69-9F-A7-11-FF-F5-BC-43-7C-87-B2-54-99-0D-A5-D5-61">
  <ModulePath>C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\myproj\v4.0_1.0.0.0__bf95fa7f15863c9f\myproj.dll</ModulePath>
  <ModuleTime>2019-09-05T16:07:28.6111533Z</ModuleTime>
  <ModuleName>myproj</ModuleName>
  <Classes />
</Module>
```

Which I believe shows OpenCover is looking in the GAC for the PDB even though it is right there in the same folder as the dll specified in `targetargs`.

I have tried setting `-targetdir` and `-searchdirs` to the `myproj.tests\bin\debug` folder (which contains the dll and pdb files) but this didn't make any changes to `opencover.xml`

Can I tell OpenCover to look in a specific location (not GAC) for the PDB?
or will I have to unregister from the GAC then run OpenCover?

Comment: Add the PDB file to project using "Add Existing Item" and then browse to folder where PDB file is located.  The in project right click on the PDB file in the reference and select option to copy to bin folder.  This ensures when the project is published that the PDB file is included in the publish data.

Comment: I am building not publishing and from what I've read the GAC doesn't store PDB files, the PDB is in the directory, it's just open cover is finding the DLL in the GAC so only looks in that location for the PDB